# Possible to match conditional from multiple values?

Tags: conditionals

I'm trying to display relationship field "members" from selected "events" if their "field" value matches a certain "query":

```
{ev_members status="open|other"}
    {if get:f}
        {if ev_members:{get:f} *= '{get:q}'}
            {ev_members:entry_id}|
        {/if}
    {if:else}
        {ev_members:entry_id}|
    {/if}
{/ev_members}
```

I'm using URL querys so, `{get:f}` is the field searched on and `{get:q}` is the query

e.g.

`{if ev_members:organisation_name *= 'Oxford|Cambridge|Oxbridge'}`

I've tried pipes, commas, spaces, and encoded pipes, commas and spaces, but nothing works. this works fine if using a single value though.

I saw another thread with a very similar issue, but the solution was an addon for an earlier vers of expressionengine, so won't work here unfortunately.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution

I'm using stash, and I was getting this info via an ajax call.

My ajax data output template is in an embed from a 'filter' template,
I use this to set some stash vars and filter ajax calls depending on URL.

The result is essentially a 'Report'

The report is also an entry, in which I have stored the "event" `entry_ids`, (`{embed:em_event_ids}`)

I set a var of all the "event" IDs I'd like to build a 'report' on

```
{exp:stash:set name="event_refs"}{!-- 
--}{exp:channel:entries
        channel="events"
        entry_id="{embed:em_event_ids}"
        other_params...
    }{f_event_ref}{if count != total_results}|{/if}{/exp:channel:entries}{/exp:stash:set}
```

I then use the `event_refs` var to filter the "members" of those "events" (in the same template file:)

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="members"
search:f_event_refs="{exp:stash:event_refs}"
{if get:f}search:{get:f}="{get:q}"{/if}
other_params...
}{entry_id}{if count != total_results}|{/if}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Doing it this way, the query with pipes (`{get:q}`), works as searching for multiple values

The data output is then what is used on the page making the ajax call